# Получаю неожидаемый вывод из метода класса

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть код:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


class main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.name is not None:
                print(self.name)
                self.name = None

    def print__(self, arg):
        self.name = arg


m = main()
m.start()
m.print__('123')
time.sleep(1)
m.print__('456')
```

Ожидаю получить в выводе 123 и 456, но в выводе None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все печатается, но это происходит очень быстро и вы не успеваете это заметить. Добавьте `time.sleep(0.1)` после `print(self.name)`

У класса `Thread` есть атрибут `name`, а вы его меняете и почему `self.name is not None` начинает возвращать `True`, а не `False`. Если везде `self.name` поменять на другое(к примеру `self.name_`) то все заработает как вы хотите

Comment: Да 456 вывело но почему выводит None?

Comment: @BlackSquare потому что `self.name is not None` вернул `True`, место `is not` используйте `!=`. Также было замечено что если наследоватся `Thread` то возвращается `False`, а если не наследоватся то возвращается `True`

Comment: Эх.. Читал я, читал, а так ничего и не понял ((